# Windows 10 shutdown closes app. Is there a log of applications that it closes?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I'm noticing that Windows 10 closes an app on shutdown.  It does it so quickly, and I can't see the application name. . .  Is there a way to view this in the system log?  If not, how can I determine this?

Comment: The only place would be Event Viewer if it is logged.  A number of apps will warn you if you are going to lose data, thus giving you an opportunity to cancel and save the file.

Comment: John:  Do I understand that the shutdown process does not log the applications that it causes to shutdown?  This seems like shoddy system programming on the part of Microsoft.

Comment: The only place is Event Viewer. There is no other log. Also I think just abnormal shutdowns are logged